# Vue 3 How update sum of all subtotals on change

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have an app that collects data from a form then pushes a new counter object to an array (counters) then renders a counter component that can increment and decrement to update a subtotal property for that counter.

I am struggling with how to render a grandTotal of all subtotals as they change. I tried using a computed property but it only renders subtotal from last counter added.

This is my AddCounters component

```
<template>
  ... form
    <div class="total-price-wrapper">
      <p class="total-text">Total Price {{ getTotals }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="counters-wrapper">
    <ul class="counters-list">
      <li
        class="counter-item"
        v-for="(counter, index) in counters"
        :key="index"
      >
        <Counter :counter="counter" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Counter from "./Counter.vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      counters: [],
      grandTotal: 0,
      price: "",
      type: "",
      location: "",
      quantity: 0,
      counterId: 0,
      subtotal: null,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Counter,
  },
  methods: {
    addCounter() {
      let newCounter = {
        id: this.counterId + 1,
        type: this.type,
        location: this.location || "In & Out",
        price: this.price,
        quantity: this.quantity,
        subtotal: this.subtotal,
      };

      if (this.price !== "" && this.type !== "") {
        this.counters.push(newCounter);
      }

      this.price = "";
      this.type = "";
      this.location = "";
      this.quantity = 0;
      this.subtotal = null;

      this.counterId = newCounter.id;
    },
  },
  computed: {
    //This only works on last counter rendered
    getTotals: function () {
      const grandTotals = this.counters
        .map((counter) => {
          console.log("Subtotals", counter.subtotal);
          return counter.subtotal;
        })
        .reduce((prev, curr) => (prev = curr), 0);
      return grandTotals;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is what my counter component looks like.

```
<template>
  ... UI methods below are wired up
    <div class="counter-subtotal-wraper">
      <label class="counter-subtotal-label">Subtotal</label>
      <span id="" class="counter-subtotal-display">{{ counter.subtotal }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    counter: Object,
  },
  methods: {
    deleteCounter() {
      console.log("Delete Counter Called");
    },
    incrementQty(counter) {
      counter.quantity += 1;
      this.getSubtotal(counter);
    },
    decrementQty(counter) {
      if (counter.quantity > 0) {
        counter.quantity -= 1;
        this.getSubtotal(counter);
      } else {
        counter.quantity = 0;
      }
    },
    getSubtotal: function (counter) {
      let count = counter.quantity;
      let price = counter.price;
      let subTotal = count * price;
      counter.subtotal = subTotal.toFixed(2);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getTotals: function () {
      const grandTotals = this.counters
        .map((counter) => {
          console.log("Subtotals", counter.subtotal);
          return counter.subtotal;
        })
        .reduce((prev, curr) => (prev = curr), 0);
      return grandTotals;
    },
```

In the `reduce` above, you're setting the `prev` to be equal to the current value. In other words, you're overwriting the value every time, not doing addition.

Instead you should be adding to `prev`:

```
getTotals: function () {
      const grandTotals = this.counters
        .map((counter) => {
          console.log("Subtotals", counter.subtotal);
          return counter.subtotal;
        })
        .reduce((prev, curr) => prev += curr, 0);
      return grandTotals;
    },
```

You may also condense the `map` and `reduce` like so:

```
getTotals: function () {
      const grandTotals = this.counters
        .reduce((prev, counter) => prev += counter.subtotal, 0);
      return grandTotals;
    },
```

## Edit

`counter.subtotal` is a String, so it needs to be cast a a Number before doing addition.

```
getTotals: function () {
      const grandTotals = this.counters
        .reduce((prev, counter) => prev += Number(counter.subtotal), 0);
      return grandTotals;
    },
```

Comment: I missed that `subtotal` is being converted to a String by `toFixed`, so it's doing string concatenation instead of addition. You can convert `counter.subtotal` to a Number before doing addition. @MikeHaslam

Comment: Thanks again It means a lot to me. I missed the string conversion also